# How to customize property name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object having structure

```
const row = { data : { name : 'hello',version : '1.2'
}};
```

I have function which tell what data you want

```
function getData (temp)
{
  // temp could be name or version
  return row.data."temp";   
}
```

I want result like if I call `getData("name")` it should result in **"hello"**
and if call `getData("version")` is called it should result **"1.2"**. In JavaScript.

Comment: Use bracket notation: `row.data[temp]`.

Comment: @harshita Just a heads up, you spelled "Assistant" wrong on your profile

Comment: @GerardoFurtado exactly that's right i already try to suggest that one.

Comment: This is quite basic. You may want to go back and review the tutorials and documentation you have been studying. Here's a [place to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
row = { data : { name : 'hello',version : '1.2'
}}

function getData (temp)
{
  return row['data'][temp] 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... Now my code is working

Comment: In general, `row.data` is preferable to `row['data']`, and many linters will complain about the latter.